# Getting output on frame instead of terminal (Perl-Tk)

Tags: linux, perl, user-interface, perltk

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Tk;
# Main Window
$mw = new MainWindow;
$label = $mw -> Label(-text=>"Hello folks") -> pack();
$button = $mw -> Button(-text => "Click here to Flush rules",
                -command =>\&flush) -> pack();
MainLoop;

sub flush {
$mw->messageBox(-message=>"Initiating flushing.. click on OK button");
system ("iptables -L");
system ("iptables -F");
system ("iptables -L");
}
```

I made this code and what it does is that when a user click on the Button a message box appears

[image]

Then when I click on OK button it calls the subroutine `flush` and then the output is shown on terminal like this:

[image]

I want it to be appear on the same message box. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer of this question at perlmonks.

The link of the post at perlmonks is-> http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=920414

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tk;

# Main Window
my $mw = new MainWindow;
$mw->geometry('+100+100');

my $label = $mw -> Label(-text=>"Hello folks") -> pack();
my $button = $mw -> Button(-text => "Click here to Flush rules",
                -command =>\&flush) -> pack();
MainLoop;


sub flush {
$mw->messageBox(-message=>"Initiating flushing.. click on OK button");
# the script hangs here, until the messagebox OK button is pressed.

my $text = $mw->Scrolled('Text')->pack();

#my $out1 =  `iptables -L`;
my $out1 =  `ls -la`;
$text->insert('end',"$out1\n");
$text->see('end');

#my $out2 =  `iptables -F`;
my $out2 =  `dir`;
$text->insert('end',"$out2\n");
$text->see('end');

#my $out3 =  `iptables -L`;
my $out3 =  `ps auxww`;
$text->insert('end',"$out3\n");
$text->see('end');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use system

capture STDOUT/STDERR ( qx, IPC::System::Simple, IPC::Run...)

update label (as simple as updating $textvariable ... see Tk demo program widget for example )